# Remove Opera Mobile blue border around <a> links

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, opera

I have an webapp, where buttons are created with `<a>` elements, and all have `href` set to `#`. I want to remove blue border around `<a>` links during mouse click, because Opera Mobile annoyingly highlights all `<a>` elements, which has same `href` set.

Example picture:

[image]

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

I think Opera may be looking for something a little stricter on the outline element.

Try:

`a:focus { outline:0px solid #fff; }`

The 'solid' and 'colour' will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% because I can't really test, but did you try adding `outline: none;` to the css for links? You may need to add it to `a:focus` and/or `a:target`

Uh-oh:

> Spatial navigation: Spatial Navigation
>   is an Opera feature whereby each
>   element available for activation is
>   put into a collection. When the user
>   moves a joystick or clicks specific
>   keys, the focus is moved to the next
>   element in the collection. This
>   element is typically highlighted with
>   a blue or black border. Links, form
>   controls, and elements with onclick
>   handlers are added to the collection.

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/characteristics-of-widgets-on-mobile-pho/

Comment: I tried it now (even with !important rule) ( a, a:focus, a:target, a:active { outline: none } ), but Opera still highlights all links.

Comment: I wouldn't mind that blue border (I understand accessibility rules), but the fact it highlights every link on page is bit annoying.

Comment: It sounds like opera thinks of that as a "feature" so there probably isn't any way to disable it.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a, a:active, a:focus {outline:none}
```

Also if you are having trouble on a Flash object/embed, you can:

```
object, embed {outline: 0}
```

Comment: I tried it now (even with !important rule) ( a, a:focus, a:target, a:active { outline: none } ), but Opera still highlights all links.

Comment: Try this one: {outline-offset:-2px;}

Comment: Tried it, no effect. Maybe it's not possible to remove it completely...At least, I hoped I can remove highlight of links with same `href`.

Answer (score 0):

Use div's with onclick() handler, instead staight `<a>` or buttons:
Example:
In CSS:

```
#home-send{
background: url(gfx/button.png) no-repeat;}
```

On page:

```
<div id="home-send" onclick="next('NEXT ACTION');"></div>
```

On click on the DIV the action will take place ,**but no outline borders effect**.

I hope this help

Answer (score 0):

To remove the Blue border use this on TOP of you CSS file

```
:focus { outline: 0 solid; }
```

or

```
:focus { outline: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and none of the answers here worked. However, I recently found a solution that worked for me (A little late to the party however...).

Try:

```
:focus{
    outline: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
}
```

If that doesn't work, you can go more specific like:

```
a, a:active, a:focus {
    outline: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
}
```

You need to actually set an outline first, then make it transparent.

https://dev.opera.com/tv/tweaking-spatial-navigation-for-tv-browsing/